# Multisite subdirectory not working

Tags: 7, multi-sites

Reading the guide, this seemed like it would be a walk in the park but I can't get to an install screen for my subdirectories.

I have created my database and users without any issue, I've got my httpd setup and ready for when I get Drupal to pick this up.

I followed the guide https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site and followed steps through to 6 except I do not get a install page I simply get the root site that is installed already.

My current url is dev.sitename.com and I am trying to get it to work with dev.sitename.com/fr and dev.sitename.com/de

All permissions are correct so I believe my issue is how I have done the /sites/ step? In this folder I have "all", "default", "sitename.fr" and "sitename.de". The codebase I want to use is "default" and within the "sitename.fr/.de" directories I have the settings.php file setup which looks to be correct. I got my 2 symbolic links by running the command "ln -s . de" and "ln -s . fr".

If I can get to the install page my problems will be sorted. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory should be named `dev.sitename.com.fr` not sitename.fr. Also, you may find it easier to create a `sites.php` file from `example.sites.php`. I recommend that over directory naming.

Comment: Thank you I had included everything in the folder name except the dev. part at the beginning. Thank you that let me see that I had a flaw in my understanding of how that section worked. All working now! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the .com in your directory names.
So your two sub-directories should be named sitename.com.fr and sitename.com.de. 
Also make sure you declare these sites in your sites.php file to link the symbolic links to the folders, at the end of it add:

```
$sites = array("sitename.com.fr" => "fr", "sitename.com.de" => "de");
```